# UIWebView LoadRequest only works once?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a webview that loads in the viewDidLoad Event a website:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.mypage.net/geschenke/allproducts.php";
NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteURL];
[webView2 loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

This works good.
On this page, I have some metainformation, e.g. the ID of the product that is just shown.

Now I have a UIButton in my app, when I click it, the following code gets executed:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender{
NSString *lastId = [webView2 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('iphone-4').innerHTML;"];


NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mypage.net/geschenke/allproducts.php?lastId=%@&likeIt=0", lastId];




NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

NSLog(fullURL);

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteURL];
[webView2 loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

As you can see, I am loading the same page, but with new parameters (lastID and likeIt).
I use the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to parse the ID easily.

The NSLog(fullURL) command logs the *correct* url! When I copy and paste it in the browser, it works.

The source code itselfs works, too. When I load www.google.de instead the webView navigates to the new page.

Any ideas?

Thanks you!

Comment: could you log some info in the uiwebview delegate methods, to see if the finished load or fail with error callbacks are being called. That might give you some more info.

Comment: Also NSURLRequest has a cache policy that you can set, where you can tell it to ignore any cached versions, which may be getting pulled in. Apples caching seems to be quiet mystical sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try ignoring the cache:

```
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0.0]
```